# Example of "information stored elsewhere by the interrupting thread can be used to provide further instructions for the interrupted thread" in JCIP

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading Java Concurrency in practice.

I have question about the content in 7.1.3: "Responding to interruption".

```
Cancellation can involve state other than the interruption status; interruption can be used to get the thread’s attention, and information stored elsewhere by the interrupting thread can be used to provide further instructions for the interrupted thread. (Be sure to use synchronization when accessing that information.)

For example, when a worker thread owned by a ThreadPoolExecutor detects interruption, it checks whether the pool is being shut down. If so, it performs some pool cleanup before terminating; otherwise it may create a new thread to restore the thread pool to the desired size.
```

I cannot imagine a scenario about "information stored elsewhere by the interrupting thread can be used to provide further instructions for the interrupted thread."

I think maybe `ThreadPoolExecutor` is the example, but the shutdown information is stored by `ThreadPoolExecutor` instead of the interrupting thread.

Could someone provide an example of "information stored elsewhere by the interrupting thread can be used to provide further instructions for the interrupted thread"?

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` is not a thread. An instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` is not a thread. The thread that calls `shutdownNow()` is the interrupting thread.